# Untouched AWS Lambda/S3 function suddenly now working issue

Tags: aws-lambda

So this morning I completed an AWS Lambda and S3 function that allows the on the fly resizing of an image - based on this tutorial - https://github.com/sagidM/s3-resizer

This morning it worked perfectly and hours later (nothing in code changed, no one else has access), I'm suddenly getting access denied returned when trying to invoke the function.

The lambda function still tests perfectly - but trying to invoke an on-the-fly image doesn't work anymore and absolutely nothing has changed. Can anyone help or explain this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information in your question to offer any help. Can you track down a specific line of code that is giving the error, the include it in your Question?

Comment: well thats the thing - the lambda code is testing successfully - its just that after a few hours I'm getting this - 

https://fergbucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/200x200/steph.jpg

Yesterday this would have worked. No code has changed - I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: I can see that image just fine. Are you saying that the function is giving an error, or the resulting images are giving an error when you try to access them?

Comment: Sorry I mnaually created that image last night?? Try this url instead.

http://fergbucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/220x220/steph.jpg

I get XML returned..

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>CB6CD0DBFD9EBE33</RequestId>
<HostId>
XCcYE4+K27bN5QP63L2M2cRpv77q1JstUy6ESUrVV6uDgjxGb4+qD9wt93Gjd69h3R+2dqgumqA=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: For me, it is saying `NoSuchKey`.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about... now why this message? Nothing in the code has changed! Its incredulous... makes no sense what so ever...

Comment: If somebody does not have access to a bucket, and they try to access an object that does not exist, Amazon S3 will return `Access Denied` rather than `NoSuchKey` because it is more secure -- S3 doesn't want to reveal whether an objects exists unless the user has permission to access such an object. You appear to have opened your `fergbucket` to the entire world, because I can list all the contents (not good from a security standpoint). Your bucket contains a `200x200` directory, but not a `220x220` directory (mentioned in your last comment).